# Does the SqlConnection close during the using portion of a code block?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following code which iterates through a series of SQL statements to update various tables in my SQL Server database.
The first of the statements sets the database to single user so we can be sure no on else can connect and cause any blocking. The last of the statement reverts it back to multi user.

```
using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(MyConn))
{
    try
    {
        Connection.Open();                                              // Open Connection
        SqlCommand cmd;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> KVP in _SQL)
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(KVP.Key, Connection); 
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();           
        }
        Connection.Close();                                             // Close Connection

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log("Error : " + e.ToString());
    }
}
```

However, the other day I got the following error message.

> Database 'XXXXXXX' is already open and can only have one user at a time.

Does SQL server drop the connection between query executions and is the connection not held until connection.Close() in this scenario?

Comment: You should not be calling `Close` on the connection yourself. If you create it with a `using` statement, it will be disposed at the end of that block and that will close it implicitly. That said, there's no reason that that code would be closing the connection between iterations of the loop.

Comment: Thank you, I shall remove the close portion. 
The error was mid-loop, It was actually on the last statement, setting the database back to multi user.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're running in between the single / multi user but i would suggest looking into an alternative design. Locking is usually not so bad, you can use transactions and do your own locking if that's a problem for you. Using SINGLE USER to run some DMLs is like closing the whole road grid just to fix a little pot hole

Answer (score 4):

You are looping through your commands in a try catch block. This means if there is an exception after the first command, the last command which reverts the database to multi-user will never be executed.

The command that sets the database usage to multi-user should be called in a finally block statement.